# Use of SCRIPTDATAVALUE in FLV File

Tags: flv

The FLV spec from Adobe notes that you can embed values into the FLV. In particular, there is a data tag SCRIPTDATAVALUE which allows a number of different types to be embedded. One of these is the Object type (type 3).

I haven't found any further description of what these data values are used for, and I am wondering whether they allow ActionScript code to be embedded in the video, and if so, what the execution model is for that code (e.g. when does it get called, what elements of the file does the code have access to, etc).